# how to search non indexed field in apache lucene search

Tags: lucene

I have a table indexed 5 columns & i have 5 other columns left without indexing in it. Is it possible to search  using the non indexed column using lucene query?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can only search for data that is indexed.